# why am I getting /dev/fd/62: Read-only file system

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

```
$ exec >&- > >(tee file >/dev/tty)
bash: /dev/fd/62: Read-only file system
```

Can someone help explain thie above shell, what does it mean? and how should I solve the error

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I can't recreate the error. The command sends the shell's output to the file `file` and also duplicates it to the terminal.